# Which system apps need internet?

Tags: networking, 20.04, internet, firewall, lts

I want to set up the firewall gufw to only allow a browser and only OS stuff that needs the internet (to get updates, and whatever else).  It's 20.04 LTS and I'm just using it to browse the internet and nothing else.

So I can easily use the default setup, but I'm wanting to know if I can further restrict it to only certain apps.  I just don't know what other apps need internet..

I'm also interested in maybe blocking certain IP addresses at some point as well.

Comment: There is no application-level filter that is confirmed to work on Ubuntu 20.04 - all the application layer filters to control Internet access based on application have been for the most part deprecated or have suffered bitrot from not being developed anymore over the years.

Comment: Why not simply *ask your system* which applications are using the network at the moment? The system does not hide this information from you, and will readily tell you. Ubuntu is Open Source, and the developers have no patience for any application that tries to be secretive or nefarious.